# How to make wildcard for files to unwrap with ":" as separator instead of " "?

Tags: bash

For example, having typed:

```
bash$ java -cp lib/*.jar Something
```

How to quickly get to

```
bash$ java -cp lib/library1.jar:lib/library2.jar:lib/library3.jar Something
```

(or equivalent)

Is there a shortcut like <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>*</kbd>, but with ":" instead of " "?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is as convenient as I can muster

```
CP() { local IFS=:; echo "$*"; }    # perhaps put this in your .bashrc

java -cp "$(CP lib*/jar)" Something
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.  The `$(...)` construct is command substitution.  It runs what's inside and pastes the output back on the command line in its place.

```
java -cp $(for i in lib/*.jar; do echo -n $sep$i; sep=:; done) Something
```

Comment: It is not convenient; it's a little in-place program that is often even longer than just TAB-complete the libraries one by one (I do such things when there are many libraries). Is there a convenient way? Can I add a shortcut like Alt+*, but with other separator?

Comment: this is what Ant or make is for. The way to make it convenient is to use those or to write a bash script and execute it with `./myscript`.